aws lambda function does not work when importing a function from a different file in a different folder
I have the simplest possible Python function and I am able to deploy it as an AWS Lambda function.
The code of the function is this
handler.py
import json
def ask(event, context):
    body = {
        "message": f"Go Serverless v3.0! Your function executed successfully! Length ",
        "input": event,
    }

    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(body)}

    return response

The serverless.yml is this
service: rag-se-aws-lambda
frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11

package:
  individually: true

functions:
  ask:
    handler: handler.ask
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: post

Now I develop a function my_function in the file src/my_function.py and I want to use it in handler.py like this
import json
from src.my_function import my_function

    def ask(event, context):
        my_function()
        body = {
            "message": f"Go Serverless v3.0! Your function executed successfully! Length ",
            "input": event,
        }
    
        response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(body)}
    
        return response

When I deploy, with the same serverless.yml configuration, the new version of my function I get the following runtime error
Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'my_function'
By the way, if the file my_function.py is moved to the same root folder where handler.py is defined, everything works.
What should I do to be able to import a function from a different folder when using AWS Lambda python functions?

Since folder location makes difference, simply add your src folder to Python's sys.path to let it find your stuff:
import json
import sys
import os

src_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'src')
sys.path.append(src_dir)

from my_function import my_function

def ask(event, context):
    my_function()
    body = {
        "message": "Go Serverless v3.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        "input": event,
    }

    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(body)}

    return response

